# Angular 2: Array.push not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i push the item into the array, item is pushed but problem is that all items in array becomes same as the last item pushed.

```
pushspecification() {
        this.specificationSaveDetailList.push(this.specificationsaveDetail);
    }
```

Here is the plunker code: [plunker_Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/825wWwUY4dKW4x0GzzDc?p=preview)
In this plunker example i select item from the dropdown and provide the description and click add button and table is populated with array item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are binding pushing same object with its reference to an array element. So when you are updating `specificationsaveDetail` object reference it updates the all elements of array as they are references of same element.

To make it work, you have to create a new object copy and push it inside array. For then same you could use `Object.assign`

```
pushspecification() {
    this.specificationSaveDetailList.push(Object.assign({}, this.specificationsaveDetail));
}
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SuLzMMTKoguBvLRvkkoU?p=preview)

Comment: @Amir Glad to know that, Thanks :)

Comment: today you can use `pushspecification() {
    this.specificationSaveDetailList.push({...this.specificationsaveDetail});
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
Array.push(Object.assign({}, this.utility));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below approach for when you are adding the elements into array.

```
const element: IEmployee[] = []; //initialize the array
element.push(employee);
```